# Movable Expansion-Panel in Angular using Material

Tags: html, angular, typescript, user-interface, material-design

I have an array of objects

```
  listA  = [
  { name : "Pink Floyd", 
    sequence : 1,
    favSong : "Shine On You", 
    favMember :[
    {artist : "Nick Mason"}
  ]},
    { name : "Guns and Roses", 
    sequence  :2,
    favSong : "November Rain", 
    favMember :[
    {artist : "Slash"}
  ]},
    { name : "Led Zeppelin",
    sequence  :3,
    favSong : "Stairway To heaven", 
    favMember :[
    {artist : "Jimmy page"}
  ]},
]
```

and I am displaying them as multiple expansion panels on the UI. I want to add a feature where i can drag individual expansion panels and and change the order in the which the names are displayed. I tried using sortableJs but i cant figure it out.

here is the **HTML**

```
<div>
    <strong>My favorite bands in order  : - </strong>
</div>
<hr />
<hr />



<div class="row mt-3">

            <div class="nomarLR mt-1 float-left col-12" *ngFor="let x of listA;let i =index">
                <mat-accordion multi="false" class="cus-accordion-style2 col-12" class="nomarLR nomarTB">
                    <mat-expansion-panel class="nomarLR nomarTB">
                        <mat-expansion-panel-header class="nomarLR nomarTB">
                            <mat-panel-title class="nomarLR nomarTB">
                                {{x.name}}
                            </mat-panel-title>
                        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <div *ngFor="let y of listA">
                            <span *ngFor="let z of y.favMember"> {{z.artist}} </span>
                        </div>
                    </mat-expansion-panel>
                </mat-accordion>
            </div>

</div>

<!-- why is multi not working ??-->
```

Can someone please help me with it. Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-gnrzcl) 
Also, when ever the user moves the expansion panels it should push the array objects in a different array with updated sequence.

Comment: I love the contents of your array.

Comment: Thank You. Rock Music is love. Any solution tho?

Comment: Sadly, I haven't got a clue. Good luck though..

Comment: You have helped me a lot, Happy new year :)

Comment: Happy new year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- https://angular-qlpqhb.stackblitz.io
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qlpqhb?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html

Added **(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"** event for drag and drop events and added cdkDrag for dom elements which you want to drag

**HTML:**

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"> // added html for drag and drop
  <div class="nomarLR mt-1 float-left col-12" *ngFor="let x of listA;let i =index" cdkDrag> // cdkDrag elements which are draggable.
                <mat-accordion multi="false" class="cus-accordion-style2 col-12"
                    class="nomarLR nomarTB">
                    <mat-expansion-panel class="nomarLR nomarTB">
                        <mat-expansion-panel-header class="nomarLR nomarTB">
                            <mat-panel-title class="nomarLR nomarTB">
                                {{x.name}}
              </mat-panel-title>
                        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <div *ngFor= "let y of listA">
            <span *ngFor="let z of y.favMember"> {{z.artist}} </span>
          </div>
                    </mat-expansion-panel>
                </mat-accordion>
        </div>
 </div>
```

**TS**

```
sortedArray = []


listA  = [
{ name : "Pink Floyd", 
favSong : "Shine On You", 
favMember :[
{artist : "Nick Mason"}
]},
{ name : "Guns and Roses", 
favSong : "November Rain", 
favMember :[
{artist : "Slash"}
]},
{ name : "Led Zeppelin", 
favSong : "Stairway To heaven", 
favMember :[
{artist : "Jimmy page"}
]},

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.listA, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you have done that was missed by OP in order to make it work? IMO, it will be helpful for future readers as well.

Comment: @NicholasK comments and how to implement added.

Comment: @MenimE was the solution helpful, Please accept and upvote if it was helpful to you